# Issues with using Screen to split terminal on WSL - Ubuntu 14.04.5, Screen 4.1.0

Tags: gnu-screen, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to split the screen to view VIM and the terminal at the same time and I am unsure if I am doing something wrong.  The directions I've seen say to install screen (was already installed for me version 4.1.0) and to input "screen" into the terminal then input "Ctrl a |", this is not working for me.

When I type "screen" in the terminal it outputs "Cannot make directory '/var/run/screen': Permission denied".  When I input "sudo screen" the screen clears and outputs "[screen is terminating]" from which the terminal works but the screen hotkeys still do not seem to work. If I input "screen" again, it clears the screen again.

"Info Screen" brings me to the documentation page that says to use "C-a" which I am assuming means "Ctrl a" but that does not seem to work (I am holding ctrl and pressing lowercase 'a').  This is my first post so please let me know if I can improve the format of my question (not sure of the correct tag for WSL) and thank you very much for your time.

edit: I have been using tmux for a week now with no problems and I have been avoiding the inherent problem of screen not functioning as planned. From root directory, when I type "ls -ld /var/run/screen" or "ls -l /var/run/screen", I receive the same output "ls: cannot access /var/run/screen: No such file or directory". When I input "ll" or "ls -l", I do not see the directory var.

Comment: I was able to split my terminal using tmux.

Comment: If you have resolved your problem it is encouraged to answer your own question so that others with the same issue can benefit from your experience. Thank you!

Comment: This issue ("permission denied") should be solved: please [edit] your question with the output of `ls -ld /var/run/screen` and of `ls -l /var/run/screen`.

Answer (score 2):

Update @ 2016-09-09:

**screen should now work fine on Windows 10 RS2 Insiders builds 14915+**. See [release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/bashonwindows/issues/774) and [update in associated bug #774](https://github.com/microsoft/bashonwindows/issues/774#issuecomment-243893844) for more details.

[PS: Please accept this if it answers your question. Thanks.]

---

2016-08-29 - There's an [issue in WSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/774) in Win10AU that prevents screen from operating correctly. [The team is working on a fix](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/774#issuecomment-237876502) and will release via the Windows Insiders builds in the coming weeks. Sorry for the inconvenience.

In the interim, you might want to [try tmux which works well](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/06/08/tmux-support-arrives-for-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/).

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I have been using tmux for a week now and its been very helpful.

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/bashonwindows/issues/774#issuecomment-313815937 about making the "Permission denied" problem go away whenever you restart WSL's bash.

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal, start screen by typing 'screen' and then hitting enter. Now all commands start with Ctrl-a. That's hold the Ctrl key while pressing lower case a. The next character you enter after that will be the command. Here we go...

Press Ctrl-a and then Shift-S (capital S) That will split the screen. If you press a lowercase s you may need to exit and restart you terminal and screen. Next...

Press Ctrl-a and then Tab. This will put focus on the lower screen. In that screen press Ctrl-a and then c. That will start a new session in that window.

Press Ctrl-a and then Tab to switch back to the upper screen.
Pick the one you want your editor to be in and start it as you normally would. Use Ctrl-a and then Tab to go back and forth as desired.
A fairly good list of instructions can be found and this [LINK](https://www.bangmoney.org/posts/2004-03-24-screen.html)

Comment: "When I type "screen" in the terminal it outputs "Cannot make directory '/var/run/screen': Permission denied"." He cannot start screen (like myself)